# DrawState with specific width and height

Tags: c++, winapi

I'm trying to draw an disabled icon with the method `DrawState`. My problem now is that the width (parameter `BUTTONWIDTH`) and height (parameter `BUTTONHEIGHT`) are ignored by this method.

Is there another method available or do I need to change some parameters?

```
void CPgFPButton::DrawButtonIcon(LPDRAWITEMSTRUCT lpdis, HICON hicon)
{
    RECT rect = lpdis->rcItem;
    rect.left = 3;
    rect.top  = 3;

    if (!m_Enabled)
        DrawState(lpdis->hDC,NULL, NULL, (LPARAM)hicon, (WPARAM)NULL,
                  rect.left, rect.top, BUTTONWIDTH, BUTTONHEIGHT, 
                  DST_COMPLEX | DST_ICON|DSS_DISABLED);
    else            
        DrawIconEx(lpdis->hDC,
                   rect.left,rect.top,hicon,
                   BUTTONWIDTH - 3 * 2,
                   BUTTONHEIGHT - 3 * 2,0,NULL,DI_NORMAL);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd162496(v=vs.85).aspx):

> The image type and state. This parameter can be one of the following type values.
>   DST_COMPLEX
>   DST_ICON
>   …
>   This parameter can also be one of the following state values.
>   DSS_DISABLED
>   …

You are passing `DST_COMPLEX | DST_ICON|DSS_DISABLED`. It looks like you should decide whether to use `DST_COMPLEX` or `DST_ICON` and not use both. Remind: width and height are only used for `DST_COMPLEX`.